# Sorting a bunch of arrays into one array, using importance as a weight

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

PHP. I have three arrays, filled with 50 items each: $articles, $quotes, $links. Each item in each array has a line of content and a date.

The objective is to create one array, sorted by date (newest to oldest), that weights based on the importance of the array type. For example, it should always show more articles than quotes, and more quotes than links. For example:

Article, article, article, quote, article, link, article, article, quote, article, article, quote, article, link.

Is there any simple way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are the articles, quotes and links arrays already sorted by date?

Comment: Yes, they are sorted by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the mod operator.

```
$result = array();
$i = 0;
$count = 0;
while( true ) {
  $i++;

  $result[] = array_pop( $articles );
  if (++$count >= 50) break; // 50 items is enough

  if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) { // one quote every 3 articles
       $result[] = array_pop( $quotes );
       if (++$count >= 50) break;
  }

  if ( $i % 5 == 0 ) // one link every 5 articles
       $result[] = array_pop( $links );
       if (++$count >= 50) break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can sort each of the three arrays on date, then do a manual merge sort based on (date,importance). Before the merge sort it's probably worth to put the three arrays in one array and write a generic merge sort, so you can easily add new types to the system later.
- You can add a custom field for each record which flags the importance, merge the three arrays, then use a built-in sort with a custom comparison based on (date, importance). It's very easy to implement this one.

uhm.. sorry for the misundertanding, I thought you want to sort elements based on date and if that's equal based on importance :/